# Stiglitz: movement capital vs labor, effect on living standars

Tags: open-economy-macro

Stiglitz argues that increasing free movement of labor would be a much more effective way of increasing living standards, compared to free movement of capital (see for instance [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PCuFcJRE6XI) video).

Does someone know which theoretical frameworks have been used to derive such conclusions? (I am looking for papers published in peer reviewed journals or theory books).

Comment: This question could be improved by linking to a place where he argued such a point.

Comment: that s why i included the video. I did not find any academic reference yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Roy model ( a much celebrated model in labor economics) deals with this issue. It can be arguably be directly mapped to this issue.